# 'ruby uuid' file or directory not found error using apache and sso

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, single-sign-on, passenger

I am trying to deploy a rails application using apache and passenger. I have also integrated it with Okta for authentication. Though everything seems to be working fine after bypassing the authentication or by using thin/webrick server. I am getting the following error in my error logs if I use apache:

> **Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /nonexistent/.ruby-uuid):**

It stops execution just after reaching saml init function. Does anyone has any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was because apache didnot have permission on some child folder in the tmp folder of the rails app.